# How to make a row selection in a table with a Qt widget in a cell

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtablewidget

In my Windows C++ application, I am creating a table of type QTableWidget. The first visible cell in each row is the checkbox. The problem is that if there is a widget in a cell, I cannot highlight the entire row when clicking on any cell. All cells are highlighted, except for the cell with the checkbox. I need to highlight the entire row including the cell with the checkbox

Here is my table code, where I fill in the table header and create checkboxes in each row of the table.

```
void myClass::ShowTable(void) {
    ui.tableWidget->setColumnCount(ui_columns_positions.size());
    ui.tableWidget->setRowCount(device_table_.dev_list.size());
    for (const auto& column : ui_columns_names) {
        ui.tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderItem(ui_columns_positions.at(column.first), new QTableWidgetItem(QString::fromStdString(column.second)));
    }
    ui.tableWidget->setColumnHidden(ui_columns_positions.at(dev_table_columns::Id), true);

    for (int i = 0; i < device_table_.dev_list.size(); ++i) {
        const device dev = device_table_.dev_list[i];

        const QString id = QString::number(dev.Id);
        const QString name = QString::fromStdString(dev.name);

        //............................................

        auto* check_box = new QCheckBox();
        check_box->setChecked(dev.is_active);
        connect(check_box, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, [i, this](int state) {
            switch (state) {
            case Qt::CheckState::Checked:
                device_table_.dev_list[i].is_active = true;
                break;
            case Qt::CheckState::Unchecked:
                device_table_.dev_list[i].is_active = false;
                break;
            }
        });

        ui.tableWidget->setCellWidget(i, ui_columns_positions.at(lnb_table_columns::IsActive), check_box);

        ui.tableWidget->setItem(i, ui_columns_positions.at(lnb_table_columns::Id), new QTableWidgetItem(id));
        ui.tableWidget->setItem(i, ui_columns_positions.at(lnb_table_columns::Name), new QTableWidgetItem(name));
        
        //............................................

    }

    ui.tableWidget->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);
    ui.tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
        ui.tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui.tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui.tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
    ui.tableWidget->resizeRowsToContents();

}
```

I've tried binding different click event handlers to a table cell to ensure that the entire row is selected, including the cell with the checkbox:

```
connect(ui.tableWidget, &QTableWidget::cellClicked, this, [=](int row, int column) {
        // Выделяем всю строку
        for (int col = 0; col < ui.tableWidget->columnCount(); ++col) {
            QTableWidgetItem* item = ui.tableWidget->item(row, col);
            if (item) {
                item->setSelected(true);
            }
        }
        });
```

However, nothing happened. It always turns out a cell with a checkbox is not highlighted, as in the figure:
[image: mytable]

I also tried different styles to simulate the highlighting effect for the entire line:

```
QString styleSheet = "QTableWidget::item:selected {"
                      "background-color: #a8c2db;" // Highlight color for table cell
                      "}"
                      "QTableWidget::item:selected QCheckBox {"
                      "background-color: transparent;" // Transparent background for the checkbox in the selected cell
                      "}"
                      "QTableWidget::item:selected QCheckBox::indicator {"
                      "background-color: transparent;" // Transparent background for the checkbox indicator in the selected cell
                      "border: none;" // Remove the border of the checkbox indicator
                      "}"
                      "QTableWidget::item:selected QCheckBox:checked {"
                      "background-color: transparent;" // Transparent background for checked checkbox in selected cell
                      "}";

ui.tableWidget->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```

But this also proved unsuccessful.
Tell me, how can I highlight the entire row of the table, including the cell with the checkbox, when clicking on any cell

Comment: Any chance to merge the first 2 columns into one, where values would be provided for the `Qt::CheckStateRole`? Doing so gets you a checkbox natively, with no need to add widgets.